# How to disable space key on a password field

Tags: jquery, keyup

How to disable space key on a password field.I've tried

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#passwordId").live('keyup',function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {
       // e.preventDefault();
    return false;
    }
});
});
```

I even tried e.preventDefault();.On debugging it does enter in if but does not disable space key.Don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: try on keydown ? also it may be a compatibilty error. live method is deprecated in jQuery1.8+

Comment: yes.I did try with keydown,same result.

Comment: what jquery version you use?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you really need **live** behaviour.

```
$(document).on('keydown', '#passwordId', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 32) return false;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this http://jsfiddle.net/4FNqv/3/

```
$("input").keypress(function (evt) {

  var keycode = evt.charCode || evt.keyCode;
  if (keycode  == 32) { 
    return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this : **[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/jTntz/1/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('keypress', '#passwordId', function(e){
     return !(e.keyCode == 32);
  });
});
```

Use [.keypress()](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) event.. Also, `.live()` is deprecated.. replace with [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery("input[type='password']").keypress(function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode  == 32) { 
    return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#passwordId").on('keydown',function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {
      e.keyCode = 0; // <---
      return false; 
    }
});
});
```